# c++: how to constrain template type to copy-assignable types?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class A {}
```

How can I restrict types T to only those that are copy-assignable?
I know about `std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value` but how can I use that to restrict the type T for class A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for this, which lets you generate a nicer error message:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    static_assert (std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>, "T must be copy-assignable");
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dW6dEKWpsHBVn1qV)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) like this:

```
template<typename T, 
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>, void>> 
class A {};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5shcsz) on Compiler Explorer using the following code:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<ostream>

template<typename T, 
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>, void>> 
class A {};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    // A<std::ostream> b; // error
}
```

---

In c++20, you could write:

```
template<typename T> 
  requires std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> 
class A {};
```

which is easier to read, and produces a better error message.

And here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P3z8Tx) of that:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<ostream>

template<typename T> 
  requires std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> 
class A {};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    // A<std::ostream> b; // error
}
```

Comment: In both cases, you could whack a `(void)a;` at the end of `main()` to get rid of that "unused variable: warning. Not strictly necessary but it removes a diagnostic that may confuse some people. Also brought the code inline as well in case it ever disappears from `godbolt`.

Comment: `static_assert` leads to _far_ better error messages than `enable_if`.  Therefore `enable_if` should _only_ be used in the context of preventing specific method overloads. (and _maybe_ template specialization? Not sure)

Comment: @MooingDuck That's reasonable. The `requires` version is very readable though (and is pretty much the custom message one would write anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create your own type constraint structures from scratch, without relying even on C++11, that are still simple, easily readable, have no performance overhead and ensure a comprehensive compiler message in case of an error, you can get inspired by [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constraints).

For example, you can enforce the copy-assignability constraint by deriving your class from the following structure or constructing it in a function:

```
template<class T1, class T2> struct Can_copy {
        static void constraints(T1 a, T2 b) { T2 c = a; b = a; }
        Can_copy() { void(*p)(T1,T2) = constraints; }
    };
```